# Signing certificate is invalid,Automatic signing failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv5Wm.png)i'm trying to run app it's fine with simulator but with real device i got this problem .

1 - I disable the "Automatic manage signing" at project settings general tab then enable it but the problem still there

2 - remove key from keychain and added it again
Any Help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before this worked for me.

1) sign out from Xcode

2) goto [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/account/)

3) Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

4) revoke all certificates

5) do the same for Provisioning Profiles

6) sign in Xcode and choose Team in project